# Facebook Javascript SDK: getLoginStatus getting no response

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

As instructed by [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5), I include the SDK snippet into my page, except that since I don't have any Facebook APP and I was just trying to build a custom share button on my page, I leave parameter "app-id" as `null`. To test if it is up and running, on console I execute

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
      console.log(response)
})
```

while I am logged in FB. However, it returns `undefined`, which means there is no response. What is wrong? Is this because I didn't assign a "app-id"?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to create an FB app first. Any reason why you are not able to create an FB app?

Comment: I just don't get what app to create. I was just trying to build custom share buttons on my page, and was lead to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279759/multiple-facebook-shares-on-one-page, which makes me think I need to follow the instruction and install the SDK first. Actually I am pretty confused what JDK has to do with APPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you're calling `getLoginStatus` from and in what order. It needs to be inside your `fbAsyncInit` function:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
          appId      : 'your-app-id',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.4'
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
          console.log(response);
      });
}
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

That should load the SDK, initialize everything, then get your login status.

Comment: Thanks. I am on the phone and will try this out as soon as I get to a computer.